# Pick another column value depending on column value (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

In my frontend application I have a function that is called pick(VALUE,'col1','col2','col3'). If the VALUE is 2 the value in col2 should be picked.

This is very handsome for replacing long code using "case when", "switch case" or "if else" calculations.

I have tried to find a similar function in Postgres, but no luck so far. Seen some function array() and values() mentioned, but cannot find the correct syntax.

The goal is to set an return on of three column values depending on first column value.

Pseudo code (not working):

```
Select status values(column1,column2,column3)from code
```

I know I can do this by using "case-when-then-else-end", but I am looking for a shorter way to achieve the same thing.

Jsfiddle showing the principe. But I only want to pick ONE value depending on type:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0b41/10

Comment: Are `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `columnN` of the same type?

Comment: So you want _multiple_ columns based on the value of code_type (one column for each type)?

Comment: No, I want ONE value based on the exact type of code. The original question was how I can pick ONE value from another column based on type.

Comment: But your SQLFiddle creates three columns, one for each code_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of values from pr_* columns, then pick one of them in this way:

`(array[prl_1,prl_2,prl_3])[code_type]`

Here is a simple demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0b41/23

```
select *,
       (array[prl_1,prl_2,prl_3])[code_type]
from code
left join prl on prl_id =1
```

Comment: Right on target, simple and straightforward. Thank you!

Comment: Another question: What if the code_type is zero=0. What value is picked up?

Comment: Null is returned when an index is less than 1 Or greater than a size of the array.

Comment: So you have to have a "case when code_type=0" to deal with code_type = 0 in together with the array?

Comment: @sibert from your question, the `pick()` function is also 1 based (`'col2'` is the 2. parameter after `VALUE`), so this would work the same. If you want to start with `0` instead, you should just add `+ 1` to `VALUE` / `code_type` (in both ways), like `(array[...])[value + 1]` or `pick(value + 1, ...)`.

Comment: The function pick() in my frontend app has the first picked value as 0, so there is no problem. But thank you for the smart tip of +1!